# d3.js force directed graph search

Tags: javascript, search, select, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to implement a search function on a d3 force directed graph example.
When I type in the search query in the text field, relevant items will be shown and the irrelevant ones will fade out.

I have implemented the methods searchUpdate and count as shown in the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Rj5/11/).

I need some help to fade the items. Currently `d3.select("svg")` fades the whole graph, while `d3.select("#"+n.id)` produces an error.

Answer (score 1):

When you `d3.select("svg")` you're selecting the `SVG` canvas and setting its `opacity`. What you want to do is

```
    d3.selectAll("circle")
```

or

```
   d3.selectAll("circle.node")
```

and apply the `opacity` there.

Then what you want to do is select the circles that match by ID using `d3.select("#"+n.id)` but to do so you'll have to create an id when you create the circles, like

```
  .attr("id", function(d,i) {return "circle"+i})
```

Otherwise you don't have an id to select with.