# Search node in force directed graph using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I don't have clue about search node in graph by entering id in input text box.
I wanted to do that when user enter id in text box at that time key-up event execute and search for id in nodes. If node found then zoom that node. please help me to search node in force directed graph. Please give me small example about searching node.

Comment: This has come up a number of times, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715127/search-for-an-element-in-d3-force-layout-or-tree) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449033/d3-js-force-directed-graph-search).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an identifier on either the data or the node element.

[Here is an example of the latter.](http://plnkr.co/edit/MOczs02DNeUJGzXAPdMd)

That example is not quite what you're after but you should be able to figure it out from there.